# Can somone help me understand this stacktrace?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, stack-trace

Is there any way I can decode this stacktrace? I made a game in Unity version 2021.3.6f1. A lot of people is experiencing this crash on Android

The title of the crash is
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE)

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004e178  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+168)
  #00  pc 0000000000552064  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2260)
  #00  pc 0000000000013990  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 0000000000012fb4  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+320)
  #00  pc 000000000038410c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::AddGlobalRef(art::Thread*, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>)+268)
  #00  pc 000000000039671c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::NewGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+632)
  #00  pc 00000000041b24b4  /data/app/~~B7OIo8HRogb5Zg_6VmNHQg==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_5
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a C level crash.  SIGABORT is sent when the C library detects a problem that its not safe to continue from.  For example memory corruption in some datastructures.  It's occuring in a function called NewGlobalRef, which marks a Java object as having a reference so the garbage collector thinks it can't be collected.  C code calls this if it needs to keep a Java object around for a while.

The fact it crashed there generally means the object its calling it on isn't a valid Java object.  This generally happens if a C library screwed up and kept it around past it being a valid Java object-  for example if it forgot to add a reference, passed it to another thread, and then returned from the function where it was passed in.  However there could be other reasons.

Unfortunately there's no easy fix to this.  If its not reproducible, I'd ignore it.  If it is, I'd be looking at anywhere you pass objects from Java to C as a possible cause, and if you're writing any C level code double check that nothing is passed between threads without bumping the global ref count.